# add google authentication to **Existing** .net core 2 web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

TL;DR - how to add authentication to an existing default core 2 web api project that was started without auth.

Details - 
I've got an existing .net core 2 web api project **with no authentication** configured and I'm using entity framework core.

It was opened like -

**PIC 1 - No Auth Selected**

[image: No Auth Selected]

I'd like to add Google authentication to my **existing project** as if it were opened with

**PIC 2 - Individual user accounts selected**

[image: Individual User Accounts Selected]

but I can't find any resource regarding adding **those capabilities + scaffolding and migrations** - all I can find are links regarding upgrading from core v1 to 2.

- [Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)
- [Configuring Google authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  Upgrading what?  The google linked shows you how to add Google Auth to an asp.net core app.  Can you try updating your question?  Regards.

Comment: hey ! thank you ! updated - hope its clearer. Basically I started out with the default template ( without authentication) and now I'd like to add google auth to my project without having to copy out all my work to a new one ..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm really struggling to get mine working and so many example use the MVC template, I just want the API.

Comment: No! I did not! Any advice you have or suggestions how to edit the question...

Comment: When you choose `Individual User Accounts`, you get the MVC controllers for registration, login, etc - Do you want all of this stuff too? If not, can you be more specific in what you want?

Comment: yes ! all of it! or at least the relevant stuff to web api. Either way - i want to avoid the pain of migrating my code to a new project just because i want to add auth.
thanks for reply !!

Comment: You say you don't want to create a new project and migrate your code across - that seems reasonable. Have you considered creating a new project and instead migrating the auth stuff from that into your existing project?

Comment: considered - not implemented yet :P seems weird there isn't a documented 'modify' flow..

Comment: I found the following blog post when trying to do the same thing:
https://jonhilton.net/2017/05/10/secure-you-asp-net-core-mvc-and-web-api-app-using-google/

Answer (score 19):

Add packages

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google
```

Then in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
    services.AddAuthentication(
            v => {
                v.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                v.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            {
                googleOptions.ClientId = "CLIENT ID";
                googleOptions.ClientSecret = "CLIENT SECRET";
            });
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication()
       .UseMvc();
}
```

A minimal working example here: 
https://github.com/mjrmua/Asp.net-Core-2.0-google-authentication-example